# RESTful concurrent user management

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

I have a website in AngularJS. And a backend that is basically dumbed down to a RESTful API. Login currently works liket this: 
User provides login credentials -> send to server -> Validate informations and deliver a token that will be used for future requests on the API. 
 The API itself can be used anonymously as well. 
Now I understand that in a RESTful environment, I shouldn't be using Sessions, but what if I wanted to show users that have been online in the last 15minutes? How would I determine if the user that was online within the last 15 minutes was authenticated or anonymous? 
 I am not exactly looking for any code example but rather food for thought.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you too add date field to user entity something like `lastAccessDate` and with every API request for user you update `lastAccessDate` to current date (`now()`).

To get all users that were active during last 15 minutes your just need to make query in your DB with condition: `now() - lastAccessDate < 15 minutes`

To track anonymous users you need to add separate entity `guests`, `activities`, `shadow users`, `anonymous users` could be good choice for that case.

Does this sound something helpful?

Comment: This is pretty much what I am doing right now but what about anonymous users?

Comment: If you want to track them also, you need to create some kind of entity for them too, e.g. `shadow users`, `guests` or maybe some other entity called `acitivities` and sure `anonymous users` will do too :)

Comment: Despite this not exactly containing the solution this put me on the right track anyway. Thank you very much gevorg :)